# Анимация движения мячика по заданной траектории

Tags: javascript, css3, svg, анимация, canvas

У меня есть следующий код мяча в начале туннеля:

```css
body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0; min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex; align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 100%; height: 160px;
  background: #fbf2d4;
}

.ball {
  width: 40px; height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #f48024;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ball"></div>
</div>
```

Какими средствами и технологиями можно реализовать анимацию движения мячика в некотором тоннеле по заданной траектории, как это указано на рисунке ниже?

[image: Анимация мячика по заданной траектории]

Необходимо воспроизвести такую анимацию. Но, прежде чем это сделать, нужно понять, отчего отталкиваться, чтобы применить нужные средства выбранной технологии. То ли это заданная траектория, по которой двигается мячик. То ли это летящий мячик, отскакивающий от верхней и нижней стен. Для ответа этот выбор большого значения не имеет. Важнее всего сама реализация создания эффекта такой анимации и подробное ее описание.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Вариант animateMotion с кнопками управления

Самое сложное на мой взгляд, это создать пиксель в пиксель траекторию, как на картинке в вопросе, поэтому остановлюсь подробнее.

- Создаем SVG файл для загрузки в векторный редактор:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="900" height="133" viewBox="0 0 900 133" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAFqM.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

- Далее, прямо по траектории движения на рисунке наносим узловые точки
  с помощью инструмента "Рисовать кривые Безье - <kbd>Shift + F6</kbd>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Сохраняем файл `*.svg`
- Копируем `path` из файла, вот он и будет траекторией движения в
  команде `<mpath>`

`<mpath xlink:href="#trace" />`

- Далее пишем команду анимации `animateMotion` для движения шарика

***Одна кнопка `forward`,- одно движение, только вперед***

```js
var animation1 = document.getElementById("forward")
function forwardSVG(){
     animation1.beginElement();
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
        <button id="btn1" onclick="forwardSVG()">forward</button />
        
</div>  

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="25 4 900 190" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="background:#FEF2D4;"> 

<defs>
<path id="trace" stroke="blue" fill="none" d="m0 31c0 0 22.6 3.9 31.9 10.1 15.8 10.6 25.6 28.4 36.6 44 10 14.2 15.4 31.4 26.5 44.7 9.5 11.4 19.9 23.3 33.5 29.2 10 4.4 23.2 5.6 32.7 3.5 13.8-3 25.8-12.6 35.8-22.6 14.1-14.1 23.6-35.1 31.9-50.6 7.1-13.1 17.1-26.5 25.7-36.6 8-9.4 19.9-15.7 31.9-18.7 11.3-2.8 24.2-2.9 35 1.6 15.1 6.2 25.9 20.4 36.2 33.1 10.5 13 16.1 29.2 25.3 43.2 6.5 9.9 13.3 20.1 21 28.8 7.1 8.1 16.4 14.8 26.5 18.7 8.3 3.2 17.6 4.2 26.5 3.1 9.9-1.3 19.8-5.1 28-10.9 9.8-6.9 16.3-17.6 23.3-27.2 7.8-10.6 13.8-22.4 21-33.5 7.2-11.1 13.5-23 22.2-33.1 5.9-6.8 12-13.9 19.8-18.3 8.5-4.7 18.3-7.8 28-7.8 11.3 0 23 3.4 32.7 9.3 10.2 6.3 17.2 16.9 24.5 26.5 9 11.8 15.5 25.2 23.3 37.7 5.5 8.7 10 18.2 16.7 26.1 8.1 9.4 16.9 19 28 24.5 9.7 4.8 21.1 7.6 31.9 6.6 11.5-1.1 22.6-6.5 31.9-13.2 7.7-5.6 13.1-14 18.7-21.8 5.1-7.1 8.7-15.1 13.2-22.6 6.4-10.6 12.4-21.4 19.4-31.5 4.6-6.6 9.2-13.3 14.8-19.1 5.9-6.1 11.9-12.4 19.4-16.3C881.7 33.8 900 31 900 31M0 163.5" />
</defs>
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAFqM.png" width="100%" height="100%" />  
<circle class="circle2" cx="0" cy="0" r="12" fill="#F48024" >
                     
     <animateMotion
       id="forward"
       dur="4s"
       begin="indefinite"
       repeatCount="1"
       keyPoints="0;1"
       keyTimes="0;1"
       calcMode="linear"
       restart="whenNotActive">
         <mpath xlink:href="#trace" />
     </animateMotion> 
      
        </svg>
```

***Несколько кнопок `forward`,`middle`, `back` -  движение вперед, от середины, назад***

```js
var animation1 = document.getElementById("forward")
function forwardSVG(){
     animation1.beginElement();
} 
var animation2 = document.getElementById("middle")
function middleSVG(){
     animation2.beginElement();
}  

var animation3 = document.getElementById("back")
function backSVG(){
     animation3.beginElement();
}
```

```html
<div id="pathContainer4">
        <button id="btn1" onclick="forwardSVG()">forward</button />
        <button id="btn2" onclick="middleSVG()">Middle</button />
        <button id="btn3" onclick="backSVG()">Back</button />
</div>  

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="25 4 900 190" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="background:#FEF2D4;">   

<defs>
<path id="trace" stroke="blue" fill="none" d="m0 31c0 0 22.6 3.9 31.9 10.1 15.8 10.6 25.6 28.4 36.6 44 10 14.2 15.4 31.4 26.5 44.7 9.5 11.4 19.9 23.3 33.5 29.2 10 4.4 23.2 5.6 32.7 3.5 13.8-3 25.8-12.6 35.8-22.6 14.1-14.1 23.6-35.1 31.9-50.6 7.1-13.1 17.1-26.5 25.7-36.6 8-9.4 19.9-15.7 31.9-18.7 11.3-2.8 24.2-2.9 35 1.6 15.1 6.2 25.9 20.4 36.2 33.1 10.5 13 16.1 29.2 25.3 43.2 6.5 9.9 13.3 20.1 21 28.8 7.1 8.1 16.4 14.8 26.5 18.7 8.3 3.2 17.6 4.2 26.5 3.1 9.9-1.3 19.8-5.1 28-10.9 9.8-6.9 16.3-17.6 23.3-27.2 7.8-10.6 13.8-22.4 21-33.5 7.2-11.1 13.5-23 22.2-33.1 5.9-6.8 12-13.9 19.8-18.3 8.5-4.7 18.3-7.8 28-7.8 11.3 0 23 3.4 32.7 9.3 10.2 6.3 17.2 16.9 24.5 26.5 9 11.8 15.5 25.2 23.3 37.7 5.5 8.7 10 18.2 16.7 26.1 8.1 9.4 16.9 19 28 24.5 9.7 4.8 21.1 7.6 31.9 6.6 11.5-1.1 22.6-6.5 31.9-13.2 7.7-5.6 13.1-14 18.7-21.8 5.1-7.1 8.7-15.1 13.2-22.6 6.4-10.6 12.4-21.4 19.4-31.5 4.6-6.6 9.2-13.3 14.8-19.1 5.9-6.1 11.9-12.4 19.4-16.3C881.7 33.8 900 31 900 31M0 163.5" />
</defs>
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAFqM.png" width="100%" height="100%" />  
<circle class="circle2" cx="0" cy="0" r="12" fill="#F48024" >
                     
     <animateMotion
       id="forward"
       dur="4s"
       begin="indefinite"
       repeatCount="1"
       keyPoints="0;1"
       keyTimes="0;1"
       calcMode="linear">
         <mpath xlink:href="#trace" />
     </animateMotion> 
        
         <animateMotion
       id="middle"
       dur="4s"
       begin="indefinite"
       repeatCount="1"
       keyPoints="0.5;1"
       keyTimes="0;1"
       calcMode="linear"
       rotate="auto">
         <mpath xlink:href="#trace" />
     </animateMotion>         

          <animateMotion
           id="back"
           dur="4s"
           begin="indefinite"
           repeatCount="1"
           keyPoints="1;0"
           keyTimes="0;1"
           calcMode="linear">
         <mpath xlink:href="#trace" />
        </animateMotion>
         </circle>
        </svg>
```

**Вариант с изображением PNG**

В SVG можно также анимировать растровые картинки.

Вместо `circle` возьмем растровую картинку теннисного мячика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var animation1 = document.getElementById("forward")
function forwardSVG(){
     animation1.beginElement();
} 
var animation2 = document.getElementById("middle")
function middleSVG(){
     animation2.beginElement();
}  

var animation3 = document.getElementById("back")
function backSVG(){
     animation3.beginElement();
}
```

```html
<style>
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
background:#84AF98;
}
.container {
width:90vw;
height:90vh;
}
</style>
<div id="pathContainer4">
        <button id="btn1" onclick="forwardSVG()">forward</button />
        <button id="btn2" onclick="middleSVG()">Middle</button />
        <button id="btn3" onclick="backSVG()">Back</button />
</div>  

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="25 4 900 190" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="background:#FEF2D4;">    

<defs>
<path id="trace" stroke="blue" fill="none" d="m0 31c0 0 22.6 3.9 31.9 10.1 15.8 10.6 25.6 28.4 36.6 44 10 14.2 15.4 31.4 26.5 44.7 9.5 11.4 19.9 23.3 33.5 29.2 10 4.4 23.2 5.6 32.7 3.5 13.8-3 25.8-12.6 35.8-22.6 14.1-14.1 23.6-35.1 31.9-50.6 7.1-13.1 17.1-26.5 25.7-36.6 8-9.4 19.9-15.7 31.9-18.7 11.3-2.8 24.2-2.9 35 1.6 15.1 6.2 25.9 20.4 36.2 33.1 10.5 13 16.1 29.2 25.3 43.2 6.5 9.9 13.3 20.1 21 28.8 7.1 8.1 16.4 14.8 26.5 18.7 8.3 3.2 17.6 4.2 26.5 3.1 9.9-1.3 19.8-5.1 28-10.9 9.8-6.9 16.3-17.6 23.3-27.2 7.8-10.6 13.8-22.4 21-33.5 7.2-11.1 13.5-23 22.2-33.1 5.9-6.8 12-13.9 19.8-18.3 8.5-4.7 18.3-7.8 28-7.8 11.3 0 23 3.4 32.7 9.3 10.2 6.3 17.2 16.9 24.5 26.5 9 11.8 15.5 25.2 23.3 37.7 5.5 8.7 10 18.2 16.7 26.1 8.1 9.4 16.9 19 28 24.5 9.7 4.8 21.1 7.6 31.9 6.6 11.5-1.1 22.6-6.5 31.9-13.2 7.7-5.6 13.1-14 18.7-21.8 5.1-7.1 8.7-15.1 13.2-22.6 6.4-10.6 12.4-21.4 19.4-31.5 4.6-6.6 9.2-13.3 14.8-19.1 5.9-6.1 11.9-12.4 19.4-16.3C881.7 33.8 900 31 900 31M0 163.5" />
</defs>
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAFqM.png" width="100%" height="100%" />  
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/muZHy.png" x="2" y="-20" width="35px" height="35px" >
                     
     <animateMotion
       id="forward"
       dur="6s"
       begin="indefinite"
       repeatCount="1"
       keyPoints="0;1"
       keyTimes="0;1"
     calcMode="linear"
       rotate="auto">
         <mpath xlink:href="#trace" />
     </animateMotion> 
        
         <animateMotion
       id="middle"
       dur="6s"
       begin="indefinite"
       repeatCount="1"
       keyPoints="0.5;1"
       keyTimes="0;1"
     calcMode="linear"
     rotate="auto">
         <mpath xlink:href="#trace" />
     </animateMotion>         

          <animateMotion
           id="back"
           dur="6s"
           begin="indefinite"
           repeatCount="1"
           keyPoints="1;0"
           keyTimes="0;1"
           calcMode="linear"
       rotate="auto">
         <mpath xlink:href="#trace" />
        </animateMotion>
         </image>
        </svg>
```

Comment: "Далее, прямо по траектории движения...", разрешите поинтересоваться, что за программу вы используете?

Comment: @Voprositel  [animateMotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion) то есть рисуешь кривую и этой командой двигаешь объект вдоль этой кривой

Answer (score 7):

Вариант с изменением значений абсолютного позиционирования с помощью JavaScript:

```js
let container = document.querySelector(".container");
let ball = document.querySelector(".ball");

let maxX = container.clientWidth - ball.offsetWidth;
let maxY = container.clientHeight - ball.offsetHeight;

let size = 30;
let start = null;
let duration = 1;

function step(timestamp) {
  let progress, x, y;
  if (start === null) start = timestamp;

  progress = (timestamp - start) / duration / 2000;

  x = progress * maxX / size;
  y = 2 * Math.sin(x);

  ball.style.left = Math.min(maxX, size * x) + "px";
  ball.style.top = maxY / 2 + (size * y) + "px";

  if (progress >= 1) start = null;
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  background: #fbf2d4;
  border: 1px solid #f1e5bc;
}

.ball {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #f48024;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ball"></div>
</div>
```

Добавим второй мячик:

```js
let container = document.querySelector(".container");
let ball = document.querySelector(".ball");
let ball2 = document.querySelector(".ball2");

let maxX = container.clientWidth - ball.offsetWidth;
let maxY = container.clientHeight - ball.offsetHeight;

let size = 30;
let start = null;
let duration = 1;

function step(timestamp) {
  let progress, x, y, y2;
  if (start === null) start = timestamp;

  progress = (timestamp - start) / duration / 4000;

  x = progress * maxX / size;
  y = 2 * Math.sin(x);
  y2 = 2 * Math.cos(x);

  ball.style.left = ball2.style.left = Math.min(maxX, size * x) + "px";
  ball.style.top = maxY / 2 + (size * y) + "px";
  ball2.style.top = maxY / 2 + (size * y2) + "px";

  if (progress >= 1) start = null;
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  background: #fbf2d4;
  border: 1px solid #f1e5bc;
}

.ball,
.ball2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.ball {
  background: #f48024;
}

.ball2 {
  background: #bcbbbb;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ball"></div>
  <div class="ball2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Два шарика

При добавлении второго шарика понадобится второй `path` трассы движения.
Для этого в векторном редакторе дублируем первый path для первого шарика и вертикально отражаем копию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В коде всё будет в двойном количестве: 2 path трассы для движения шариков, 2 кнопки запуска:

```js
var animation1 = document.getElementById("forward1")
function forwardSVG(){
     animation1.beginElement();
} 
var animation2 = document.getElementById("forward2")
function forwardSVG2(){
     animation2.beginElement();
}
```

```html
<style>
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
background:#84AF98;
}
.container {
width:90vw;
height:90vh;
}
</style>

<div id="pathContainer">
        <button id="btn1" onclick="forwardSVG()">forward1</button />
        <button id="btn2" onclick="forwardSVG2()">forward2</button />
        
</div>  
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         viewBox="25 4 900 190" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="background:#FEF2D4;">  


   <path id="traceTop" stroke="yellowgreen" stroke-width="3" fill="none" d="m0 31c0 0 22.6 3.9 31.9 10.1 15.8 10.6 25.6 28.4 36.6 44 10 14.2 15.4 31.4 26.5 44.7 9.5 11.4 19.9 23.3 33.5 29.2 10 4.4 23.2 5.6 32.7 3.5 13.8-3 25.8-12.6 35.8-22.6 14.1-14.1 23.6-35.1 31.9-50.6 7.1-13.1 17.1-26.5 25.7-36.6 8-9.4 19.9-15.7 31.9-18.7 11.3-2.8 24.2-2.9 35 1.6 15.1 6.2 25.9 20.4 36.2 33.1 10.5 13 16.1 29.2 25.3 43.2 6.5 9.9 13.3 20.1 21 28.8 7.1 8.1 16.4 14.8 26.5 18.7 8.3 3.2 17.6 4.2 26.5 3.1 9.9-1.3 19.8-5.1 28-10.9 9.8-6.9 16.3-17.6 23.3-27.2 7.8-10.6 13.8-22.4 21-33.5 7.2-11.1 13.5-23 22.2-33.1 5.9-6.8 12-13.9 19.8-18.3 8.5-4.7 18.3-7.8 28-7.8 11.3 0 23 3.4 32.7 9.3 10.2 6.3 17.2 16.9 24.5 26.5 9 11.8 15.5 25.2 23.3 37.7 5.5 8.7 10 18.2 16.7 26.1 8.1 9.4 16.9 19 28 24.5 9.7 4.8 21.1 7.6 31.9 6.6 11.5-1.1 22.6-6.5 31.9-13.2 7.7-5.6 13.1-14 18.7-21.8 5.1-7.1 8.7-15.1 13.2-22.6 6.4-10.6 12.4-21.4 19.4-31.5 4.6-6.6 9.2-13.3 14.8-19.1 5.9-6.1 11.9-12.4 19.4-16.3C881.7 33.8 900 31 900 31M0 163.5" />
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/muZHy.png" x="2" y="-20" width="35px" height="35px" >
                     
     <animateMotion
       id="forward1"
       dur="6s"
       begin="indefinite"
       repeatCount="1"
       keyPoints="0;1"
       keyTimes="0;1"
       calcMode="linear"
       rotate="auto">
         <mpath xlink:href="#traceTop" />
     </animateMotion> 
        
    </image>  
    <path id="traceBottom" fill="none" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="3" d="m0 163.5c0 0 22.6-3.9 31.9-10.1 15.8-10.6 25.6-28.4 36.6-44 9.9-14.1 15.3-31.4 26.4-44.7 9.5-11.4 19.9-23.3 33.5-29.2 10-4.4 23.2-5.6 32.7-3.5 13.8 3 25.8 12.6 35.8 22.6 14.1 14.1 23.6 35.1 31.9 50.6 7.1 13.1 17.1 26.5 25.7 36.6 8 9.4 19.9 15.7 31.9 18.7 11.3 2.8 24.2 2.9 35-1.6 15.1-6.2 25.9-20.4 36.2-33.1 10.5-13 16.1-29.2 25.3-43.2 6.5-9.9 13.3-20.1 21-28.8 7.1-8.1 16.4-14.8 26.5-18.7 8.3-3.2 17.6-4.2 26.5-3.1 9.9 1.3 19.8 5.1 28 10.9 9.8 6.9 16.3 17.6 23.3 27.2 7.8 10.6 13.8 22.4 21 33.5 7.2 11.1 13.5 23 22.2 33.1 5.9 6.8 12 13.9 19.8 18.3 8.5 4.7 18.3 7.8 28 7.8 11.3 0 23-3.4 32.7-9.3 10.2-6.3 17.2-16.9 24.5-26.5 9-11.8 15.5-25.2 23.3-37.7 5.5-8.7 10-18.2 16.7-26.1 8.1-9.4 16.9-19 28-24.5 9.7-4.8 21.1-7.6 31.9-6.6 11.5 1.1 22.6 6.5 31.9 13.2 7.7 5.6 13.1 14 18.7 21.8 5.1 7.1 8.7 15.1 13.2 22.6 6.4 10.6 12.4 21.4 19.4 31.5 4.6 6.6 9.2 13.3 14.8 19.1 5.9 6.1 11.9 12.4 19.4 16.3 8.1 4.2 26.3 7 26.3 7" /> 
    
    <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoB43.png" x="2" y="-20" width="35px" height="35px" >
                     
     <animateMotion
       id="forward2"
       dur="6s"
       begin="indefinite"
       repeatCount="1"
       keyPoints="0;1"
       keyTimes="0;1"
       calcMode="linear"
       rotate="auto">
         <mpath xlink:href="#traceBottom" />
     </animateMotion> 
        
    </image> 
</svg>
        
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Попытался сделать что-то похожее, работает только в Chromium браузерах.

`--leftPercent` и `--topPercent` это положение круга на экране браузера.
0 - начало, 100 - конец

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --colorCircle: white;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.holst {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.holst::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--colorCircle);
  filter: invert();
}

@property --leftPercent {
  syntax: "<number>";
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

@property --topPercent {
  syntax: "<number>";
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

.circle {
  --size: 20vmin;
  --leftPercent: 0;
  --topPercent: 0;
  --left: calc( 100vw - var(--size));
  --leftTotal: calc( var(--left) * var(--leftPercent) / 100 );
  --top: calc( 100vh - var(--size));
  --topTotal: calc( var(--top) * var(--topPercent) / 100 );
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  background-color: var(--colorCircle);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid orange;
  transform: translateX(var(--leftTotal)) translateY(var(--topTotal));
  animation: animCircleX 4s infinite alternate linear,
             animCircleY 1s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes animCircleX {
  0% {
    --leftPercent: 0;
  }
  100% {
    --leftPercent: 100;
  }
}

@keyframes animCircleY {
  0% {
    --topPercent: 0;
  }
  100% {
    --topPercent: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="holst">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' а, нет, получилось сделать linear анимацию

Comment: Спасибо за наводку на `@property`. Что-то я отстал совсем...

Comment: @UModeL слабо поддерживается